# Seed method is not called on update-database, Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have the following `DbContext` class. Everything about EF is working fine (migrations, relations, etc.), the only thing that is not working for me is the seeding. I've tried many different solutions but nothing seems to work. Anybody got an idea?

When I run update-database it seems like its executing the seed method but nothing is updated in the database.

```
public class ProgramContext : DbContext
{
    public ProgramContext() : base("ProgramContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ProgramContext>(new MyDbInit());
    }

    public DbSet<Bin> Bins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }


    public class MyDbInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProgramContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProgramContext context)
        {
            IList<Status> statuses = new List<Status>();
            Status status0 = new Status("WH-RAMP");
            Status status1 = new Status("Transport > Lijn");
            Status status2 = new Status("In lijn");
            Status status3 = new Status("Retour lijn");
            Status status4 = new Status("Transport > WH");
            context.Statuses.Add(status0);

            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Bin.class

```
public class Bin
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long BinId { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public bool Full { get; set; }

    public Bin(string Barcode, Status Status, bool full)
    {
        this.Barcode = Barcode;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.Full = Full;
    }

}
```

Status.class

```
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }

    public Status(string StatusName)
    {
        this.StatusName = StatusName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to call `SaveChanges`, just seed is required

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that isn't the answer unfortunately

Comment: are you sure there are actual model changes, i.e. is the database dropped and re-created in the process?

Comment: Also tried the other classes, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

> DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
>   An implementation of IDatabaseInitializer that will DELETE, recreate, and **optionally re-seed the database only if the model has changed since the database was created**.

This might help. The Configuration class is inside migrations folder.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BookService.Models.BookServiceContext>
{
     protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
     {
        Status status0 = new Status("WH-RAMP");
        Status status1 = new Status("Transport> Lijn");
        Status status2 = new Status("In lijn");
        Status status3 = new Status("Retour lijn");
        Status status4 = new Status("Transport > WH");
        context.Statuses.Add(status0);
        context.Statuses.Add(status1);
        context.Statuses.Add(status2);
        context.Statuses.Add(status3);
        context.Statuses.Add(status4);

     }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, I will try out the DropDatabaseAlways and other classes later. Thanks:)